# C++ using the variable of type of a function pointer for instead the name of the function pointer

Tags: c++, variables, types, function-pointers

I am trying to understand function pointers: I know that in order to create a function pointer to a function ( which takes a double and returns an int  and then initialize to NULL ) I would do:

```
int (*fptr) (double) = NULL;
```

In the code I am working with I find a typedef similar to that for a function pointer

```
typedef int (CALLBACK *C_MP)(double d);

//I know I can use it with the name C_MP: 
C_MP(5.5); 
(*C_MP)(5.5);

//But then I also find in this code a declaration/definition of a variable of type C_MP like that:
C_MP mycmp = NULL;

// where later mycmd is used like that:
(*mycmp )(1.23);
```

I am puzzled by this line ( C_MP mycmp = NULL;) **Why can I declare a C_MP with the name mycmd and use that name further on in my code?** Until now I always saw people using the function pointer name ( like C_MP(5.5) or (*C_MP)(5.5);)

Comment: Function pointers and `typedef` should generally be avoided in C++, there are usually better alternatives.

Comment: Also note that `NULL` is an old C-macro kept for compatibility only. In C++ use `nullptr` for null pointers.

Comment: A pointer always holds an address even when that address doesn't refer to anything valid. A pointer is too limited to know whether or not it points at anything valid.

Comment: It's for the same reason why you can do `typedef int FOOBAR;` and then use `FOOBAR x;` later down the road to create an `int`. This is how `typedef` works, after all, so your question is a bit unclear. Are you asking what `typedef` does?

Comment: My question was: why can I use (*mycmp)(4.4) instead of (*C_MP)(4.4) ?My question is not about typedef .

Comment: "why can I use (*mycmp)(4.4) instead of (*C_MP)(4.4) ?" because that is the proper use and you cannot use `(*C_MP)(4.4)`

Comment: Because, in C++, there's a difference between a pointer, and a type.

Comment: Your mistake was probably being so certain that you can use `(*C_MP)(5.5)` that it didn't occur to you to try (and notice that you can't). This is no different from `typedef int INTEGER; INTEGER x = 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion comes from a fact, that you know wrong:

```
typedef int (CALLBACK *C_MP)(double d);

//I know I can use it with the name C_MP: 
C_MP(5.5); 
(*C_MP)(5.5);
```

This is invalid, you cannot use `C_MP` as a pointer to function, it is a type not a variable. And you can clearly see that compiler rejects it (I removed macro CALLBACK as it is irrelevant here):

```
typedef int (*C_MP)(double d);

int main() {
    C_MP(5.5); 
    return 0;
}
```

[Live code](https://ideone.com/kxDbkp)

> prog.cpp:6:10: error: invalid cast from type ‘double’ to type ‘C_MP’ {aka ‘int (*)(double)’}
> C_MP(5.5);

Later usage is correct, variable of type `C_MP` is created and then used.

To make it easier to understand look at this example:

```
typedef int myint; // myint is an alias to int
myint = 0; // wrong, you cannot assign to a type;
myint i = 0; // correct you create i of type myint which is alias to int
```

In your case `C_MP` is an alias to type "pointer to funtcion that accepts double and returns int" (whith some perks that macro `CALLBACK` does) but not a pointer itself.

Comment: thank you Slava, that helped a lot.